# Nested forEach on querySelectors

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have this nested forEeach on some DOM elements.

```
// get parallax box
var parallaxBox = document.querySelectorAll('.js-Parallax-Box');
// iterate over each parralax box
[].forEach.call(parallaxBox, function(el, _) {
     // get parallax elements
     var parallaxElement = el.querySelector('.js-Parallax-Element');
     // iterate over each parallax element
     [].forEach.call(parallaxElement, function(el, _) {
           // can't reach this el
     });
});
```

First loop is working correctly but i can't reach second, what is wrong? Can anybody help?

Comment: `querySelector` returns the first matching element.

Comment: I don't think that you need to nest your `querySelectorAll()` calls, could you show your HTML? I strongly suspect that there's an easier way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `querySelector` inside the first forEach callback, which only returns single element you can't use forEach with that. So use  `querySelectorAll` inside the callback to get `NodeList` and iterate, otherwise if  there is only single element then there is no need of forEach at all.

```
var parallaxBox = document.querySelectorAll('.js-Parallax-Box');
[].forEach.call(parallaxBox, function(el, _) {
     var parallaxElement = el.querySelectorAll('.js-Parallax-Element');
     //                change here  -------^--------
     [].forEach.call(parallaxElement, function(el1, _) {

     });
});
```